# Lightbox with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, lightbox

I want a fusion chart in my flex app to display with a Lightbox effect like the effect you get when you click on any of the charts [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/gallery/) or checkout the demos [here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

These effect have been attained with the help of javascript. How do i get the same effect via Flex? Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This would actually be a great community addition, if you wanted to release a small library for the effect. There are enough people who (like you) want to do it simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a [Flex component called PopUpThumbnail](http://joshblog.net/2008/12/04/open-source-flex-component-popupthumbnail/) that is very similar to HTML/JavaScript lightbox components.

Here's an [example application](http://www.flextoolbox.com/components/popupthumbnail/FlickrThumbs.html) that I created with it to displays Flickr images.

Comment: Oh.thats v.nice. It may most probably turn out useful for me. I now just have to display a flash movie instead of those picture. Thank a lot Josh. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I tried to make it extensible as possible so that you can display anything in the pop up. That feature not super well documented, but be sure to read my comments in the code and you can probably figure it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add a mask over the top of the whole application with the content area in the middle and the semi alpha area around it. Clicking on the surrounding mask removes the layer, and you can interact with the content area as normal (make it look like a popup rather than actually using one...)

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I will try to come up with something.